# How to get the next object?

Tags: django

here's what I have now:

```
im = get_object_or_404(Images, uid=uid)
next = get_object_or_404(Images, pk=im.pk+1)
```

but if I deleted one instance always the next will be 404 because of the pk, so how can I get directly the next?

Comment: please provide your `Images` model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.get_next_by_FOO`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO)

> For every `DateField` and `DateTimeField` that does not have `null=True`, the object will have `get_next_by_FOO()` and `get_previous_by_FOO()` methods, where **FOO** is the name of the field. This returns the next and previous object with respect to the date field, raising a `DoesNotExist` exception when appropriate.

For example, when your `Images` model has `created_at` with `models.DateTimeField`;

```
class Images(models.Model):
    ....

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So, you can use with;

```
img = get_object_or_404(Images, uid=uid)
next_img = img.get_next_by_created_at()
```

Comment: thanks, that didn't work but I made it work. I'll answer my question if you want to see it and tell me if it's good or not.

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me:

```
next = Images.objects.filter(pk__gt=im.pk).order_by('pk').first()
```

Comment: Hi moon, welcome to StackOverflow. You should explain your code and why it works, instead of just posting a bunch of code lines.